# Is there a Facebook API call to list all apps?

Tags: facebook

Do any of you know of a facebook api call (or equivalent) that can list all facebook apps?

I haven't been able to find this on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API call which will list every app ever created, as that's a privacy concern. You can find the apps that a given user is an admin of using the [`page_admin`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_admin/) table:

```
SELECT page_id FROM page_admin WHERE uid = <UID> AND type = 'Application'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a request to the `/me/accounts` endpoint on the Graph API (`http://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts`).  This endpoint lists all the user's Pages and Applications.  You could then iterate through that list and check where `category` is `Application`.

Comment: this will only list pages, but not applications - at least not anymore