# How can I get the list of facebook apps for a certain user using Graph API Explorer or another tool

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph-api-explorer

I want to build an data tool for facebook apps and I've searched for a few hours online to see if there is a way to find the app list for a specific user. Couldn't find anything. Does anyone know how to do this.

PS: I have taken a look at: [Is there a Facebook API call to list all apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890365/is-there-a-facebook-api-call-to-list-all-apps) but it did not help me

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: That link have the answer. There is no way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but it looks like it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/applications/developer

The user docs say that this is the endpoint for "The Facebook apps that this person is a developer of."

Comment: I have tried the page that you gave me and by name it does seem to be what I need. But when I access it's an empty page. Does it display something in your case?

Comment: i believe the whole api reference is buggy right now, just try it again tomorrow

Comment: I have just taken a different example and updated it with /user-id/applications/developer, worked perfectly, so yes for anyone who will have this problem just use the path that I have given above. Thanks a ton!